# Limit of the integral: $\int_0^{\pi/2}\beta^\alpha\exp\left(-\beta\cos(\theta)\right)d\theta$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I have the following integral:
$$\displaystyle J(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\dfrac{\pi}{2}\beta^\alpha\exp\left(-\beta\cos(\theta)\right)d\theta$$ where: $\alpha\gt0$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. I have to find the following limit: $$\lim_{\beta\to+\infty}J(\alpha,\beta)$$
The integral can be solved and the result is:
$$J(\alpha,\beta)=\dfrac{1}{2}\beta^\alpha\pi\left(J_0(\beta)-L_0(\beta)\right)$$ where $J_0(\beta)$ is the Bessel function of zero order and $L_0(\beta)$ is the Struve function. Unfortunatly for $\beta\to+\infty$ the two functions go both to infinity. How can be calculated the limit? I suppose it depends on the value of $\alpha\lt 1$ or $\alpha\ge1$. Thanks

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is the way to go, I expect.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\lim_{\beta\to+\infty}J_0(\beta)=0$? [Illustration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#mediaviewer/File:Bessel_Functions_(1st_Kind,_n%3D0,1,2).svg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(\beta)=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\beta\cos\theta}d\theta$. Note that
$$\eqalign{
F(\beta)&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta e^{-\beta\cos\theta}d\theta+G(\beta)\cr
&=\frac{1-e^{-\beta}}{\beta}+G(\beta)}
$$
where
$$\eqalign{
0\leq G(\beta)&=\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\sin\theta) e^{-\beta\cos\theta}d\theta\cr
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\cos\theta) e^{-\beta\sin\theta}d\theta\cr
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(\theta/2) e^{-\beta\sin\theta}d\theta\cr
&\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\theta^2 e^{-2\beta\theta/\pi}d\theta\cr
&\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\theta^2 e^{-2\beta\theta/\pi}d\theta=\frac{\pi^3}{8\beta^3}
}
$$
This proves that, for large $\beta$ we have
$$F(\beta)=\frac{1}{\beta}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\beta^3}\right)$$
It follows that
$$\lim_{\beta\to+\infty}J(\alpha,\beta)
=\lim_{\beta\to+\infty}\beta^\alpha F(\beta)
=\left\{\matrix{+\infty&\hbox{if}&\alpha>1\cr
1&\hbox{if}&\alpha=1\cr
0&\hbox{if}&\alpha<1}\right.$$